# Problematic exercise on alternate way of expressing random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, self-learning

I found this exercise on a book on probability theory, and I find it problematic.

> Let $(X, \Sigma, p)$ be a probability space, $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \Sigma$ a finite partition of $X$; and $\phi \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathcal{A}}$. Let $z$ be a random variable on $(X, \Sigma, p)$ such that $z(\omega) := \phi (A)$ if $ \omega \in A$ (That is, $z = \sum_{A \in \mathcal{A}} \phi (A) \mathbb{1}_A$.) Show that
>
> $$ \mathbb{E} (z) := \sum_{A \in \mathcal{A}} \phi (A)p(A) .$$

The point is that I am not sure if I am missing something or there is something that is not explicit and should actually be explicit.

My problem is with the $\phi$ and the fact that there is no constraints on the $A \in \mathcal{A}$, i.e. I think there should be a "constraint" such that every $\phi^{-1} (a) = A \in \mathcal{A}$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ in the range of $z$.

*Am I right? Is the exercise not completely precise?*
*If not, what am I missing?*

As always, any feedback is most welcome.
I am looking forward to your answers.
Thank you for your time

PS: A bit of context: the exercise comes with ***simple random variables**.*

Comment: This result looks identical to the “special case” described near the top of the Wikipedia article on the law of total expectation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essential is that $z$ is *measurable* and *integrable*.

For a subset $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ let $\mathcal{A}_{B}:=\left\{ A\in\mathcal{A}\mid\phi\left(A\right)\in B\right\} \subseteq\mathcal{A}\subset\Sigma$.

Then $\mathcal{A}_{B}$ is a finite collection of elements in $\Sigma$
so that $\bigcup\mathcal{A}_{B}\in\Sigma$.

Now realize that $z^{-1}\left(B\right)=\bigcup\mathcal{A}_{B}\in\Sigma$.

So $z$ is a measurable function, no matter with what $\sigma$-algebra
$\mathbb{R}$ is equipped.

No constraint on $\phi$ is needed here.

The expectation can be found by applying the linearity of expectation.

This especially because $\mathcal A$ is finite.

$$\mathbb{E}z=\mathbb{E}\sum_{A\in\mathcal{A}}\phi\left(A\right)1_{A}=\sum_{A\in\mathcal{A}}\phi\left(A\right)\mathbb{E}1_{A}=\sum_{A\in\mathcal{A}}\phi\left(A\right)p\left(A\right)$$

Function $z$ is labeled as *simple* because it only takes a finite number of values and is measurable.

When it concerns a probability space ($P(\Omega)=1$) then such a function is also integrable.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot. May I ask you something that will sound very stupid? Imagine we start with a step function that takes two values, $a_1$ and $a_2$. My problem is with a partition such that there is a set $A \in \mathcal{A}$ that is *"in between"* the two values... that's why I was looking for a partition. But, am I right - now - when I say this is automatically ruled out by $\phi (A)$, because as a function, it takes just one value at the time for every $A$?

Comment: Let $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$  only takes values in $\{a_1,a_2\}\subset\mathbb R$. If $A_1,A_2\in \Sigma$ are defined as $\{\omega\mid f(\omega)\in A_i\}$ for $i=1,2$ then they form a partition of $\Omega$. Any preimage under $f$ will belong to $\{\varnothing, A_1,A_2,\Omega\}$ so will belong to $\Sigma$. That is relevant. The fact that the set $\{a_1,a_2\}$ does not form a partition of $\mathbb R$ (there are values "in between") is *not* relevant. The focus is on preimages and not on images. I hope this makes things more clear to you.

Comment: Yes indeed. What fooled me can be exemplified in the following example: $\Omega = [0, 1]$, and $z ([0, 1/2]) = a_1$, while $z ((1/2, 1]) = a_1$. My problem was with a partition of $\Omega$ where $A_1 = [0 , 1/3]$ and $A_2 = (1/3 , 1]$, and here $\phi$ doesn't behave properly. But, as I wrote down in the previous comment, this should be ruled out, because $\phi$ is – indeed! – a function. Do you see what – stupidly – fooled me? Did I explain myself? *Am I actually right now?* Btw, really thanks a lot.

Comment: @Kolmin, yes with that partition $A_1,A_2$ you can never get this function $z$, since, by construction, $z$ is constant on every $A_i$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is bothering you here. Function $z$ is a *simple function*, since 
$$z(\omega)=\sum_{A \in \mathcal{A}} \phi(A) 1_A(\omega)$$
and partition $\mathcal{A} \subset \Sigma$. It is measurable (as are all simple functions), if that is what is bothering you, since 
$$z^{-1}(B)=\bigcup_{\substack{\phi(A) \in B \\ A \in \mathcal{A}}} A,\quad B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$$
Actually, if $\mathcal{A}=\{A_1,\ldots,A_n\}$, the only role of function $\phi$ here is to determine $n$ real values $\phi(A_1),\ldots,\phi(A_n)$ that function $z$ takes on sets $A_1,\ldots,A_n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I admit I do a bit of copy and paste with a comment I left to the other answer. First of all thanks a lot. May I ask you something that will sound very stupid? Imagine we start with a step function that takes two values, $a_1$ and $a_2$. My problem is with a partition such that there is a set $A \in \mathcal{A}$ that is *"in between"* the two values... that's why I was looking for a partition. But, am I right - now - when I say this is automatically ruled out by $\phi (A)$, because as a function, it takes just one value at the time for every $A$?

Comment: By its definition, function $z$ is constant on every set $A \in \mathcal{A}$. If by "a set in between two values" you mean that on one part of the set $z$ takes value $a_1$ and on another part value $a_2$, that is ruled out by definition of $z$.